# Как работает код на четвертой строчке?

Tags: javascript

Данный код записывает в объект количество повторений элементов массива. Совершенно не могу понять код на четвертой строчке.

```
let arr = ["z","z","a","a",];
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(elem =>{
    obj[elem] = (obj[elem] || 0 ) + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в объекте нет ключа, то `obj[key]` возвращает `undefined`. `undefined || 0` возвращает `0`. Это способ инициализировать отсутствующие ключи нулями:

> ```
> $ node
> Welcome to Node.js v12.22.10.
> Type ".help" for more information.
> > obj = {}
> {}
> > obj['z']
> undefined
> > obj['z'] || 0
> 0
> > (obj['z'] || 0) + 1
> 1
> > obj['z'] = (obj['z'] || 0) + 1
> 1
> > obj['z']
> 1
> > obj['z'] || 0
> 1
> > (obj['z'] || 0) + 1
> 2
> > obj['z'] = (obj['z'] || 0) + 1
> 2
> >
> ```

**P.S.** Это изощрённое решение. Лучше явно проверить отсутствие ключа. Хотя кода будет нужно больше, зато он легче читается.

Comment: Если в ключе не присвоено никакого значения(undefined), ему присваивается 0, а потом инкриминируется. Если идет повторное обращение к ключу, снова инкриминируется. Хорошо это понял. Если есть значение undefined после которого стоит логический оператор || и заданное значение, то идет присваивание данного нами значения вместо undefined. Если ошибаюсь исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы правы. `Инкриминруется` (преступление) -> `инкрементируется` (счётчик).